# ionic shake animation of an menu item

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework, ng-animate

Why the shake animation is not working for my menu item (which has the count)?

I have the following template for the menu:

```
<li class="item" ng-repeat="(key, value) in menuItems">
  <a ng-click="navigateTo(value.title)" class="menu-icon {{value.title | lowercase}}" ng-class="{noitems: value.count==0}" shake-me>
  {{value.title}}
  <span ng-show="value.count==0" class="status">No items available in {{value.title | lowercase}}</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

and the directive shake-me looks like:

```
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .directive('shakeMe', ['$animate', function($animate) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, form) {
        element.on('click', function() {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            if (element.hasClass('noitems')) {
              $animate.addClass(element, 'shake', function() {
                $animate.removeClass(element, 'shake');
              });
            }
          });
        });
      }
    };

  }]);
```

and shake animation (css3):

```
@keyframes shake {
  0% {transform: translateX(0);}
  12.5% {transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg)}
  37.5% {transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg)}
  62.5% {transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg)}
  87.5% {transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg)}
  100% {transform: translateX(0)}
}

.shake {
  -webkit-animation: shake 400ms ease-in-out;
  animation: shake 400ms ease-in-out;
}
```

Mentions:

- the shake class is added but the animation is not working for some reason (on iOS 8+, Safari)

  `$animate.addClass(element, 'shake', function() {
  $animate.removeClass(element, 'shake'); //this part is never called
  });`

**EDIT**

I have created [a blank demo](http://codepen.io/elsevero/pen/dYmwmd) with the same scenario, it might help to identify the issue faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 1.3.0-RC.0, `$animate` uses promises instead of callbacks.

Change to:

```
element.on('click', function() {

  scope.$apply(function() {

    $animate.addClass(element, 'shake').then(function() {

      element.removeClass('shake');
    });
  });
});
```

In your demo you are using `.shake.ng-enter`, it should be just `.shake`.

Also, you need to add some additional CSS to make it work in Safari:

```
@keyframes shake {
  0% {transform: translateX(0);}
  12.5% {transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg)}
  37.5% {transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg)}
  62.5% {transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg)}
  87.5% {transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg)}
  100% {transform: translateX(0)}
}

@-webkit-keyframes shake {
  0% {-webkit-transform: translateX(0);}
  12.5% {-webkit-transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg)}
  37.5% {-webkit-transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg)}
  62.5% {-webkit-transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg)}
  87.5% {-webkit-transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg)}
  100% {-webkit-transform: translateX(0)}
}

.shake {
  -webkit-animation: shake 400ms ease-in-out;
  animation: shake 400ms ease-in-out;
}
```

**Demo:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQaXoe